Why are my Envoy pods failing with "reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error"
I have a Contour / Envoy ingress as explained here:
https://projectcontour.io/docs/v1.17.1/deploy-options/
I'm in the process of getting some CRD versions up to date on this cluster. During this maintentance all ingress into the solution started failing. Specifically. all of the Contour pods were healthy, but the Envoy pods stated failing. All of the backend services for my application are healthy, and all public certifications are managed by cert-manager and are up to date.
The specific error in the logs I am seeing for my Envoy pods is:
│ envoy [2024-07-24 18:22:15.456][1][warning][config] [./source/common/config/grpc_stream.h:201] StreamRuntime gRPC config stream to contour closed since 16 │
│ 682s ago: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: TLS error: 268435581: │
│ SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

This ingress setup has been running for over a year without issues.
I used k9s to describe the Envoy and Contout pods. I'm using a compatible combination of k8s (1.25), Contour (1.24.4) and Envoy (1.25.6).
https://projectcontour.io/resources/compatibility-matrix/
All of my public certs are up to date and valid, and I use SSL/TLS termination at the Contour level. I was expecting Envoy to be able to communicate with Contour and start receiving traffic.

I figured this out in the wee hours of the morning, and wanted to make sure people woud be able to find an answer online.
The fact that I did an update at the same time may have had an impact (possibly it forced TLS verification in a new version of Envoy for example). But the underlying problem is that there are two sets of certificates:

the public facing certificates for TLS traffic terminated by Contour
the internal Envoy certificate used by envoy

You can find more about envoycert in the official documentation:
https://projectcontour.io/docs/v1.17.1/grpc-tls-howto/
In my case, while I had cert-manager setup to rotate the public facing certs for HTTPS traffic to contour, the backend envoycert had expired. While the certificates can be a little tricky to comprehend in a pinch, a thing to check is the age of the envoycert resource - in my case it was well over a year old. I backed this cert up using the following command:
kubectl get secret envoycert-appcorp -n flux-system -o jsonpath='{.data.tls\.crt}' \
    > envoycert-appcorp.txt


I then deleted the cert and re-ran the Contour + Envoy deployment. This regenerated the cert, and Envoy immediately stated working.
It seems obvious in hindsight, but hopefully this saves someone a sleepless night of debugging. I'm not sure why this only broke after the k8s version update, but I'd speculate something changed in the supported version of Envoy.
